# VBA copy the value,format and color of the last non empty cell of the column

Tags: excel, vba

I've been wanting to copy the value but also the format and the cell color of the last non empty cell in column B, and past it in cell B1 in all the sheets.

Here is the code I used, but I always get an error.

```
Sub copypaste()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim Lastcell As String


   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

      Lastcell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Cell
      Lastcell.Copy
      ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
      ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue


    Next ws

  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

could you please help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cell Copy in Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sCell As Range ' Source Cell Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

        ' Cells...
        Set dCell = ws.Cells(1, "B")
        Set sCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        
        ' ... or Range...
        'Set dCell = ws.Range("B1")
        'Set sCell = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        
        ' Fastest (if it covers what you need)
        dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        dCell.NumberFormat = sCell.NumberFormat
        dCell.Interior.Color = sCell.Interior.Color
    
        ' Fast
'        sCell.Copy dCell
'        dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        
        ' Slow (the selection changes)
'        sCell.Copy
'        dCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'        dCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        
    Next ws

    ' Only for the Slow version:
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You look to be declaring Lastcell as a string but treating it as a range.  Something like this would work.

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastcell As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    Set Lastcell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    
    Lastcell.Copy
    
    ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Next ws

  Set wb = Nothing
  
End Sub
```